# Merging different size csv files

Tags: matlab, export-to-csv, cell-array

I'm trying to make data analysis + import into excel much easier. 
I have 3 different data types, call them data1, data2, data3. 
I stored them in a cell array, `measurements = cell(3,99)`
The "3" represents the 3 different types of data, and each number 1-99 represents one object which I have measured.

I'm trying to merge all files of each type together, so I have 1 Excel file for data1, 1 file for data2, and 1 for data3.

data1 and data2 are row vectors, while data3 is 2D matrices. Every entry can be a different size (though none are meaningfully large).

My current attempts:

```
for ii=1:99
      data1File = sprintf('data1_%d.csv',ii);
      data2File = sprintf('data2_%d.csv',ii);
      data3File = sprintf('data3_%d.csv',ii);
      csvwrite(data1File, measurements{1,ii});
      csvwrite(data2File, measurements{2,ii});
      csvwrite(data3File, measurements{3,ii});
  end
```

This just gave me 99 csv files of each data type, which is horribly inefficient. I tried many different ways to merge them (eg, dlmwrite) but was unsuccessful.

also tried:

```
cell2csv('data1.csv',measurements(1,:), ',','2018','.');
```

Oddly, this worked on only data1, despite the fact that data2 is also expressed as a row vector. However, data1 contains larger numbers (usually close to 5.1*10^4), so I thought that decimal point may have changed things. 
I've been attempting this problem all day with no luck. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the "{" to "(" in this piece of code? and removing the for loop.

```
csvwrite(data1File, measurements{1,ii}); %change this to this
csvwrite(data1File, measurements(1,:)); %and get it out of the for loop
```

Then it sees the output of measurements as 1 array and not as 99 different single outputs.

Your data1File creates 99 differently named files, so of course you're going to have 99 different files.

*edit, this is for dlmwrite:
<s>Also when trying to append something to a file you need to use the '-append' addition.</s>

```
csvwrite(data1File, measurements(1,:),'-append'); %like so
```

If that doesn't solve it I suggest looking at the file exchange, here's one I found [Cell2csv](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4400-cell-array-to-csv-file--cell2csv-m-).

Comment: I wrote: 
`csvwrite(data1File, measurements(1,:), '-append'); `
and it gives error: "Invalid attribute tag: ,"

I'm not entirely sure what that means, are you familiar with this error?

Comment: remove the append because, it's my mistake, it's supposed to be used for dlmwrite not csvwrite. Sorry error on my part.

Comment: No worries! I should've been able to catch that myself. I have successfully used the code `cell2csv('data1.csv',measurements(1,:), ',' , '2018' , ' . '); ` to convert the first data type. However, for data2, the same exact code does not work. Every element in data2 is a row vector of the same length as data1. The only difference is that data1 is a double and each element is ~5-6 digits, while data2 is single digit integers. Do you have any idea why this may be happening? cell2csv will convert data2, except as a long list of randomly coupled integers. Very odd.

Comment: figured it out! I was displaying the data with the "fixed width" option, instead of "Delimited." Do not yet know what that means, but it helped. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @oofin Well it means the following, fixed width tries to truncate the text into pieces/columns of the exact same character length.  Delimited truncates the data whenever it encounters a limiter such like a "," or a space or a tab by example.

Comment: @oofin if this helped you, please upvote it. If it solved your problem, please accept it. If you're still having trouble and need help, please respond and ask.

Comment: I upvoted a while ago. Unfortunately, votes from young accounts are hidden to the public.